how to divide particular rows within every group
The data is:
data <- structure(list(country = c("Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", 
                         "Poland", "Poland", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
                         "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
                         "Spain"), Code = c("POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", 
                                            "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", 
                                            "ESP", "ESP", "ESP"), year = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 
                                                                           1955, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 
                                                                           1954, 1955), IV = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                                                                                                                        8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), class = "data.frame")

I want to create a new dataset "newdata" which would contain a new variable that divides the value of IV for 1955 from 1952. And so should get repeated for every "country". All the other rows and columns from "data" should be deleted in "newdata".
So in "newdata" should be a column "country" (like, Poland), column "new.variable" that divides Poland's value of IV for 1955 from 1952 (3-3=0). And this should get repeated for every country.
The expected outcome:

When there are many groups (countries), it becomes unfeasible to divide the values manually.

Can you provide a sample of the output you're expecting?  I don't understand what "new.variable" is precisely? By "divide" do you mean division?  Year/IV?  In what context does 3-3=0?  What do you want to do with the years that aren't between 1955-1952?

Poland has '3' for 'IV" in 1955, and the same value in 1952. The output ('new.variable') should contain their difference (3 minus 3, which is equal to 0).  All the other rows (like years 1950, 1951, 1953, 1954) in 'newdata' should be simply deleted in 'newdata'. I will provide an expected output in the form of a table in the updated question

Grouping by country, and accounting for the possibility that different IV values might be present for various years (I'm not sure how the full dataset is precisely structured?  Or if some countries may not have both 1955 and 1952 years present, or multiple observations per year?). Min and max will accommodate any oddities in the data: max IV value(s) of 1955 minus the min IV value(s) of 1952
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
data[,
     .(new.variable=max(IV[year==1955])-min(IV[year==1952])),
     by=.(country)]


every country in a full dataset has IV values in 1955 and 1952. Thank you for your response!

library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  summarize(new.variable = IV[year == 1955] - IV[year == 1952], .by = country)

or
data |>
  filter(year %in% c(1952, 1955)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = IV) %>%
  mutate(new.variable = `1955` - `1952`)

